# Celery in a different module than main (flask) app

Tags: flask, celery

I'm running a Flask app with celery.
I have some rest controllers which call some tasks that run with celery.

Do I have to define the tasks in the same main python file which has the flask app context?

I'd like to have celery in another module, like a "TaskRunner" module or something like that, then let the flask app/ controller use that service to call/run the actual tasks.

How can I pass the app context (or the celery instance) to the TaskRunner to that I can use celery from there? and use the `@celery.task` anotation over there?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally sorted it out by refactoring my code using blueprints.
Then I register the "celery tasks" blueprint inside of my app factory once celery instance already exists, and it works.

Answer (score -3):

There is a good explanation here http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/celery/

If that's not enough lemme know and I can give you some extra hints